# How to start a new activity from grid view present in home screen widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-gridview

I'm new to create a widget. I created a widget which displays all the installed application in grid view. I've done all the thing by using `remoteviewfactory` but the problem is that i can't launch the respective application from the widget.
I don't know what's the problem. I can sense the click by toast, and also i got the package name, but i can't launch the application.

```
ApplicationInfo info = list.get(position);
            Intent mIntent = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello " + info.packageName,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mIntent != null) {
                try {
                    context.startActivity(mIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "app not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Please tell me what's the problem.

Comment: Have you set onClickpendingIntent  on your widget?

Comment: Ya all that thing has been set. and also Toast is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay update your **onUpdate** method like this

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

More info on widgets can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: This was not the answer i was expecting. I created all things even the setonclickpendingintent is also working. but the thing is that i want to launch another application whenever i click the grid view item